# Diskpart in one bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a one bat file with diskpart script to automatize process of creating volumes. The problem is that I want to pass parameters like this:

```
diskpart /s "createVolume.bat 500"
```

where "500" is a size of volume. Of course, this solution is not working. I was trying to do something like this in bat file:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
create volume simple size=%1
format quick fs=ntfs label="userTest"
assign letter="T"
```

but in cmd it stops on "DISKPART> ". Is there any way to use diskpart with parameters passed to script?

Comment: You shouldn't have `diskpart` as the first line, just start it from `select disk 0` Also as the file is not an executable file, dont give it an executable extension, _it isn't a batch file_. I wouldn't expect diskpart to see a double quoted string as anything other than a single argument which means that even if `%1` was accepted, `500` would not be the value associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the documentation given at [this site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx), this should work:

```
@echo off
(
echo select disk 0
echo create volume simple size=%1
echo format quick fs=ntfs label="userTest"
echo assign letter="T"
) > script.txt
diskpart /s script.txt
```

Copy this code into a Batch file, for example **createVolume.bat**, and then use it this way:

```
createVolume 500
```